# How do I know when an Image is loaded in Picturebox

Tags: c#, .net

I've some huge images (7000*5000) to load simultaneously in my program, which I'm displaying in picturebox one by one. These images take some time to load in the [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b4t5f7s.aspx). At first I'm loading all the images in an `Image` array as `Bitmap`, then I'm just showing the first image in picturebox `picturebox.Image = imageArray[0]`. So I want to show wait cursor until first image is shown in Picturebox. Is there any way to know when the first image is shown on Picturebox?

Comment: How are you loading this in picturebox..please share the code..so we can help better..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the PictureBox events : [`LoadProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadprogresschanged.aspx) to show the loading progress and [`LoadCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadcompleted.aspx) to do something when it is finished.

```
private void pictureBox1_LoadProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // animate a progressbar...
}

private void pictureBox1_LoadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // done !
}
```

To make this work, you have to keep the `.WaitOnLoad` value property to False, and you have to use one of the `LoadAsync` method.