# C# .NET if image is loaded

Tags: c#, .net, loading, splash-screen

I need to find out if my pictureboxes have loaded images.
I create them and give them ImageLocation. Pictures DO load after some time but I need to check if it is loaded. I tried using

```
if(pb.ImageLocation != null){
Console.WriteLine("Loaded!");
}
```

But this shows that its loaded even if it actually isn't. Also I have a bunch of dynamic created pictureboxes:

```
void CreateBrick(int x,int y)
    {
        bricks[i] = new PictureBox();
        bricks[i].Name = "pb_b" + i.ToString();
        bricks[i].Location = new Point(y, x);
        bricks[i].Size = new Size(60, 60);
        bricks[i].ImageLocation = @"Images/brick_wall.jpg";
        pb_bg.Controls.Add(bricks[i]);
        brick.Add(bricks[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

And I have no idea how to check these...

Comment: Where do you check if these images are loaded or not? Here you create dynamically the pictureboxes and of course they are not loaded with an image

Comment: you can check at time of image location using object of string

Comment: I check it in a separate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you don't call the [Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ak7was(v=vs.110).aspx) or [LoadAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww2xzydc(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
void CreateBrick(int x,int y)
{
    bricks[i] = new PictureBox();
    bricks[i].Name = "pb_b" + i.ToString();
    bricks[i].Location = new Point(y, x);
    bricks[i].Size = new Size(60, 60);
    // You can pass the path directly to the Load method
    // bricks[i].ImageLocation = @"Images/brick_wall.jpg";
    bricks[i].Load(@"Images/brick_wall.jpg");
    pb_bg.Controls.Add(bricks[i]);
    brick.Add(bricks[i]);
    i++;
}
```

If you use Load method then then the image is loaded after the call, if you use LoadAsync you could add the event handler for the LoadComplete event.

```
bricks[i].LoadCompleted += onLoadComplete;
bricks[i].LoadAsync(@"Images/brick_wall.jpg");
....

private void onLoadComplete(Object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Don't forget to check if the image has been really loaded,
    // this event fires also in case of errors.
    if (e.Error == null && !e.Cancelled)
        Console.WriteLine("Image loaded");
    else if (e.Cancelled)
        Console.WriteLine("Load cancelled");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Error:" + e.Error.Message);

}
```

If you want to use the LoadAsync approach you still have to solve the problem how to match the complete load of a particular image to the related picture box. This could be solved using the sender parameter of the LoadAsync. This sender parameter is the PictureBox who has completed the load of the image.
You can use the Tag property and set it to "1" to mark your picturebox as loaded and to the error message in case of problems.

```
private void onLoadComplete(Object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pic = sender as PictureBox;
    // Don't forget to check if the image has been really loaded,
    // this event fires also in case of errors.
    if (e.Error == null && !e.Cancelled)
    {
        pic.Tag = "1";
        Console.WriteLine("Image loaded");
    }
    else
    {
        pic.Tag = e.Error.Message;
        Console.WriteLine("Cancelled:" + e.Error.Message);
    }
}
```

After this the pictureboxes in your bricks arrays have their Tag property marked as "1" for the loaded ones and with an error message for the ones with an error.

Comment: How does this tell when the image will load?

Comment: It cannot but without it will not load at all.

Comment: Still, it does not answer the question, hence it is not an answer

Comment: If you call Load the call is synchronous, so the image is loaded after the call, if you call LoadAsync then you use the event handler. I have written this in the first draft of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try using `LoadCompleted` event of PictureBox after you assign a ImageLocation as the way it is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can make sure images are loaded asynchronously of course.

```
pb.WaitOnLoad = false;
```

Then load the image asynchronously:

```
pb.LoadAsync("some.gif");
```

For more from stackoverflow you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551339/is-there-an-event-for-an-image-change-for-a-picturebox-control) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525407/how-do-i-know-when-an-image-is-loaded-in-picturebox)

Assign an event handler like the following:

```
pb.LoadCompleted += PictureBox1_LoadCompleted;
```

Sample event handler right from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void PictureBox1_LoadCompleted(Object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) {
  System.Text.StringBuilder messageBoxCS = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
  messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "Cancelled", e.Cancelled );
  messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
  messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "Error", e.Error );
  messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
  messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "UserState", e.UserState );
  messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
  MessageBox.Show(messageBoxCS.ToString(), "LoadCompleted Event" );
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer! +1 Maybe add example of the LoadComplete-event

Answer (score 0):

```
private stattic bool CheckUplodedImage()
{
    bool return = false;
    try
    {
        PictureBox imageControl = new PictureBox();
        imageControl.Width = 60;
        imageControl.Height = 60;

        Bitmap image = new Bitmap("Images/brick_wall.jpg");
        imageControl.Image = (Image)image;

        Controls.Add(imageControl);
        return true;
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
     return false;
   }
}
```

can check of its return

```
bool isUploded = CheckUplodedImage();
if(isUploded)
{
  \\ ...uploaded
  \\ Perform Operation
}
else
    \\ not uploaded
```